# Tomcat server.xml docbase invalid

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, server.xml

### Problem

After installing tomcat following https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04 (Where $CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat)

I added

```
<Context path="" docBase="/root/mysite/site" debug="0" reloadable="true" />
```

inside the tag

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

in opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml

However tomcat says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [/root/mysite/site] is not valid
```

I've been struggling the whole afternoon. The setup process was from my notes which was recorded just after setting tomcat up on another machine.

### My Experiments:

1. doubled checked that `/root/mysite/site` is good. All folders are 755.
2. changed docBase to `docBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT"`. Tomcat startup successful.
3. move `/root/mysite/site` to `/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT`. Tomcat startup successful.

Comment: did you restart the tomcat server after modification

Comment: @AbdulManaf Yes. You did notice my experiments.

Answer (score 0):

The `/root` folder is 700. And the guide instructed me to create tomcat's own user & group. My experiment 1 is nonsense. What a horrible mistake!